# Use slice() method to replace array items and then undo it

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I  am selecting the topic from my select menu.When i select a topic, a random item from that topic's array shows up.

When i select from topic , i replace items from first array and get the result.

When i select colors value in select menu, i replace animals array with color array and get the random item.I do same for language array but when i get animals again it is not working.

**Choose a option from select menu and then choose "animals" option.You see there is no item from "animals" array.**

What is the solution ?

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kt2hew02/)**

```
  var animals = ["horse", "cat"];
  var colors = ["black", "white"];
  var languages = ["javascript", "css"];

  function getRandom(arr) {
    return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
  }

  var random = getRandom(animals);
  $(".word").append(random);

  $("#select").change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if (val === "colors") {
      animals = colors.slice(0);
      random = getRandom(animals);
      $(".word").empty();
      $(".word").append(random);
    } else if (val === "languages") {
      animals = languages.slice(0);
      random = getRandom(animals);
      $(".word").empty();
      $(".word").append(random);
    } else {
      random = getRandom(animals);
      $(".word").empty();
      $(".word").append(random);
    }
  });
```

Comment: You redefined "animals" array. You can't get it back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you have overwritten your animal array when you select color or language option. Also no use of `slice(0)` which effectively passes whole array . Just pass array to `getRandom()` function based on select option

```
$(function() {

  var animals = ["horse", "cat"];
  var colors = ["black", "white"];
  var languages = ["javascript", "css"];

  function getRandom(arr) {
    return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
  }

  var random = getRandom(animals);
  $(".word").append(random);

  $("#select").change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if (val === "colors") {
      //animals = colors.slice(0);
      random = getRandom(colors);
      $(".word").empty();
      $(".word").append(random);
    } else if (val === "languages") {
      //animals = languages.slice(0);
      random = getRandom(languages);
      $(".word").empty();
      $(".word").append(random);
    } else {
      random = getRandom(animals);
      $(".word").empty();
      $(".word").append(random);
    }
  });
 });
```

Your modified [**JSfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/rkf3zcef/)

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to overwrite your animals array. That's why it's not working. You could also use a switch statement in this case.

```
$(function() {

  var animals = ["horse", "cat"];
  var colors = ["black", "white"];
  var languages = ["javascript", "css"];

  function getRandom(arr) {
    return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
  }

  var random = getRandom(animals);
  $(".word").append(random);

  $("#select").change(function() {
    var val = $(this).find('option:selected').val();    
    switch(val){
        case "colors":          
        random = getRandom(colors);
        $(".word").empty();
        $(".word").append(random);
        break;
      case "languages":        
        random = getRandom(languages);
        $(".word").empty();
        $(".word").append(random);
        break;
      default:        
        random = getRandom(animals);
        $(".word").empty();
        $(".word").append(random);
        break;
    }    
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting your animals array, that's the reason why it's not working properly. In order to save your resulst you should have used another variable to save your selections.

You can see I've just added a new variable called `selection` in order to get it work as expected: [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kt2hew02/1/)